# python import hook handling complex paths

Tags: python

I have the current test import hook:

```
class TestImporter(object):


    def find_module(self, fullname, path):
        print "finding ", fullname
        print "in path ", path
        return None

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        print "loading ", fullname
        return None



sys.meta_path.append(TestImporter())
import xml.etree.ElementTree
```

with the output of

```
finding  xml
in path  None
finding  xml._xmlplus
in path  ['/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/lib-python/2.7/xml']
finding  _xmlplus
in path  None
finding  xml.etree
in path  ['/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/lib-python/2.7/xml']
finding  xml.etree.ElementTree
in path  ['/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/lib-python/2.7/xml/etree']
finding  xml.etree.sys
in path  ['/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/lib-python/2.7/xml/etree']
finding  xml.etree.re
in path  ['/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/lib-python/2.7/xml/etree']
finding  xml.etree.warnings
in path  ['/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/lib-python/2.7/xml/etree']
finding  xml.etree.ElementPath
in path  ['/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/lib-python/2.7/xml/etree']
finding  xml.etree.ElementC14N
in path  ['/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/lib-python/2.7/xml/etree']
finding  ElementC14N
in path  None
```

Notice how im my code load_module was basically left blank and find_module did not return an instance of itself to load it.  To load any module one can call:

```
importlib.import_module("module_name")
```

However; based on the output results some of these modules are not even valid such as:

```
xml.etree.sys
```

or

```
xml.etree.re
```

When importing xml.etree.ElementTree, the loader attempts to import whatever the module is also importing (in this case it is sys and re). This apparently gets concatenated onto the fullname of the module. How would a loader handle that because xml.etree.re and xml.etree.re are not valid modules to load but "sys" and "re" are valid. How do you create a loader to handle some of the paths/names created by the above output?

Comment: What do you mean by "loader"? And what is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to create a custom loader that will be able to handle the import of something complex such as xml.etree.ElementTree